# localy finite basis in (R, usual metric)

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist locally finite basis in (R, usual)?

What can be suitable characterization for metric spaces which will have locally finite basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a $T_1$ space with a locally finite base $\mathscr{B}$. For each $x\in X$ let

$$\mathscr{B}(x)=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:x\in B\}\;,$$

and let $V_x=\bigcap\mathscr{B}(x)$. $\mathscr{B}$ is locally finite, so $\mathscr{B}(x)$ is finite, and $V_x$ is therefore open. If $U$ is any open nbhd of $x$, there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}(x)$ such that $x\in V_x\subseteq B\subseteq U$, so $V_x$ is the smallest open nbhd of $x$. $X$ is $T_1$, so for each $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$ there is an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $y\notin U$, and $V_x\subseteq U$, so $y\notin V_x$. Thus, $V_x=\{x\}$. It follows that $X$ has the discrete topology.

Every metric space is $T_1$, so a metric space has a locally finite base if and only if it is a discrete space. In particular, $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology does not have a locally finite base.

Comment: Will V not be always open immaterial of whether B(x) finite or not.

Comment: @Sushil: No. In a $T_1$ space $V_x$ will always be $\{x\}$, which in general will *not* be open.

Comment: so you are taking $V_x$ to be intersection of B(x) not union. RIght

Comment: @Sushil: Yikes. Yes, that was supposed to be an intersection.

Comment: sorry not related to question. But do you have any webpage? Can I get your email id?

Comment: @Sushil: I don’t have a webpage, I’m afraid. I don’t like to post my email, but if you go to the [Cleveland State University directory](https://phonebook.csuohio.edu/ADPhonebook) and search for my last name using the LAST NAME filter, you’ll find an email address that still forwards to the one that I actually use.

Comment: A family $F$ is called  $\sigma $-locally finite when $F$ is the union of countably many locally finite families. The Hahn-Morita-Stone theorem is that a $T_1,T_3$ space is metrizable iff it has a $\sigma $-locally finite base.